# How to retrieve text from url using regex in Android

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I have a url and I am trying to extract the text before the third slash. I am quite new to the concept in Android. I believe the Pattern class is used to achieve this. My problem is how to.

Take for instance: `http://name.mywebsite.com/images....` I only require everything before images. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How about the [Pattern documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: I am new at this, hence why I came here for assistance. This is not my cup of tea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the uri method getHost in java.This example will help you,

```
URI uri = new URI("http://name.mywebsite.com/images");

String host = uri.getHost();
/* It returns name.mywebsite.com/*/
```

Comment: Thanks Coder, this is an awesome respone :)